# Problems with Netbeans Code Completion during WordPress development

Tags: php, wordpress, netbeans, netbeans-platform

I use Netbeans for WordPress development, this IDE works great with WordPress but there is a problem with the code completion. As we put the PHP opening and closing tags on the same line often during WordPress development, so it give the code completion option where its not required and is very annoying.

I searched on google for this problem and find a video which describes the same problem, I am giving the link to that video, so that you people get to know what is the problem I am facing.

http://vimeo.com/109468211

Any help will be much appreciated, Thank you.

Comment: I made that video, actually i am still facing this problem, but I didn't find any solution and don't have time to play with the Netbeans' settings. If you play with the Netbeans settings under the tools > options, you may find a solution.